# stream.CopyAsync(streamDestination) its throw Stream does not support reading exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, gzip

I'm trying to compress a file for gzip, however after its compression I need to get the gzip bytes generated to generate a base64 string.

However when I try to copy the gzip stream to a memory stream it throws the exception Stream does not support reading.

I can't find a way around this problem, can someone help me?

follow the code below:

```
    public static async Task<Tuple<bool, string, string>> CompressToGzipBase64(this IFormFile formFile, Language language)
    {
        var filePath = formFile.FileName + ".gz";

        try
        {
            await using var gzipFileStream = File.OpenWrite(formFile.FileName + ".gz");
            await using var gZipStream = new GZipStream(gzipFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
            await formFile.CopyToAsync(gZipStream);

            var bytesOfFile = await ConverteStreamToByteArray(gZipStream);

            var fileInBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesOfFile);

            File.Delete(filePath);

            return new Tuple<bool, string, string>(true, fileInBase64, string.Empty);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            File.Delete(filePath);

            return language switch
            {
                Language.PtBr => new Tuple<bool, string, string>(false, string.Empty,
                    "Ocorreu um erro durante a conversão do arquivo para o formato Gzip. Por favor tente a operação novamente!"),
                Language.EnUs => new Tuple<bool, string, string>(false, string.Empty,
                    "An error occurred while converting the file to Gzip format. Please try the operation again!"),
                Language.EsEs => new Tuple<bool, string, string>(false, string.Empty,
                    "Se produjo un error al convertir el archivo a formato Gzip. ¡Intente la operación nuevamente!"),
                _ => new Tuple<bool, string, string>(false, string.Empty, string.Empty)
            };
        }
    }

    private static async Task<byte[]> ConverteStreamToByteArray(GZipStream stream)
    {
        await using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        await stream.CopyToAsync(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t read from a GzipStream in compress mode because it’s a transforming stream and not where the data is. Your data is actually in the FileStream, so you would need to read from that.

But you don't even need the FileStream, because you are not doing anything with the file, as you are deleting it at the end. The FileStream is just unnecessary and due to it needing to write to the disk very imperformant.

So just do:

```
await using var compressedStream = new MemoryStream();
await using var gZipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
await formFile.CopyToAsync(gZipStream);

var bytesOfFile = compressedStream.ToArray();

var fileInBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesOfFile);
```

Also, I would advise to use value tuples instead of tuples as these are more succint, more performant and more legible because you can name the elements.

So your whole code could be improved to:

```
public static async Task<(bool success, string base64, string error)> CompressToGzipBase64(this IFormFile formFile, Language language)
{
    try
    {
      await using var compressedStream = new MemoryStream();
      await using var gZipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
      await formFile.CopyToAsync(gZipStream);

      var bytesOfFile = compressedStream.ToArray();

      var fileInBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesOfFile);

      return (true, fileInBase64, string.Empty);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return language switch
        {
            Language.PtBr => (false, string.Empty,
                "Ocorreu um erro durante a conversão do arquivo para o formato Gzip. Por favor tente a operação novamente!"),
            Language.EnUs => (false, string.Empty,
                "An error occurred while converting the file to Gzip format. Please try the operation again!"),
            Language.EsEs => (false, string.Empty,
                "Se produjo un error al convertir el archivo a formato Gzip. ¡Intente la operación nuevamente!"),
            _ => (false, string.Empty, string.Empty)
        };
    }
}
```

You could call it then by doing:

```
var (success, base64, error) = await formFile.CompressToGzipBase64(Language.EnUs);
```

Another advise: don't just discard exception messages. You should either log the exception somewhere or include the exception text in your error message. This makes debugging and life much easier when an exception gets thrown as you don't need to guess what error/exception really occurred.

Comment: The api I am using it validates by the name of the file as well, which must contain a .gz extension, is it possible to change the name of the stream file also during the compression process?

Comment: In your code you create a gz file, write to it, and then delete it. So after CompressToGzipBase64 is called the file doesn’t exist anymore. And your code doesn’t even return the gz file name you state that is being validated. So where does the validation happen and what does it actually do? Please extend your question with the details.

Comment: Hi cKuri, so i consume an other api that validates files for me, but it only accepts a base64 string, this base64 string has to be the file (a txt, xml, excel and etc) converted to gzip format.
When this other api receives the base64 string it checks if the name of the file I'm sending has .gz at the end and then it unzips the .gz file and reads the file inside it.
So I need the process to create a .gz file for me, put the file that is in IForm inside the .gz file and then convert this .gz file to a base64 string.

Comment: Is it possible to do this process without necessarily creating the .gz file physically on the machine?

I hope that the process has now become clear.